# Riemann Integral vs. Scalar Field Integral vs. Vector Field Integral (In single variable case)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am a bit confused about the relation between these three integrals. As my textbook doesn't seem to draw a very clear distinction between them. [this is somewhat related to this question [Are regular/Riemann integrals a special case of a line integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765975/are-regular-riemann-integrals-a-special-case-of-a-line-integral)]

---

**Suppose there is a single-variable real-valued function $y=f(x)$**

The Riemann integral is then:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx,\ \ \ \text{where$\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$}$$

The Vector Field line integral is then:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\vec j\cdot \vec idx=0,\ \ \ \text{where$\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$}$$

The Scalar Field line integral is then:
$$\int_a^bf(x)|dx|,\ \ \ \text{where$\int_a^b=\int_b^a$}$$

---

The Scalar Field Integral has the same absolute value as the Riemann Integral, but different in the property $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$

The Vector Field Integral has the same property $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$ as the Riemann Integral, but different in the absolute value (in this particular case, the value of vector integral is zero).

---

**[Q1]:** Are these three types of integral inherently different things? Or they can be treated as special cases of a generalized form

**[Q2]:** When parametrize a two variable scalar field line integral.
$$\int_Cf(x,y)ds=\int_a^bf(t)\left\| {\,\vec r'\left( t \right)} \right\|dt$$
My textbook assumed that the parametrized integral is a Riemann integral, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Q1, even if an intro calculus book might not emphasize this, there are good reasons to think of what you're calling "scalar/vector field integrals" as different things. I recommend reading the beginning of Terry Tao's preprint on "[differential forms and integration](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/forms.pdf)" which discusses that distinction.

---

For Q2: The [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) is a clarification in a different "direction". Both or neither of the above could be Riemann integrals. Basically, it's a Riemann integral if the underlying definitions with limits and sums is set up in a certain way, as opposed to some other way, like the (arguably more advanced) [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration).